# pushViewController from modalViewController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

If I push a view onto a navigationController and present it modally, is it possible to push and show another view without having to first dismiss the modalViewController? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear.  "push a view onto a navigationController" and "present it modally" are 2 different operations.  However, after doing either of these, you can do either of those again.

NavCon push ViewA
      -ViewA can then push ViewB
 or
-ViewA can present ViewB modally.

NavCon show ViewA modally

-ViewA can then push ViewB  // this is a little weird, but possible.
 or
-ViewA can present ViewB modally.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm sorry if I wasn't very clear. I'm trying to figure out if there's away to present a view modally, and then present more views using the standard navigation controller animation, without having to first dismiss the initial modal view.

Comment: Do you mean: NavCon presents viewA modally, and then NavCon presents or pushes viewB without dismissing ViewA?  No - it's a stack and there is one thing at the top of it at all times.

Comment: If you mean push views behind the modalview? Then I'd say no. What you can do is pop up a modal view then push another view in the modal view's space. Then you can dismiss the second pushed view and return to wherever you were on your stack before you called the modal view

Comment: I'm just looking to present a modal view, and then animate it away to a new view using the same animation as you would regularly see with a navigation controller. Is this possible?

Comment: Present the modal viewController showing what you want to show.  Sometime during the modal VC's life, instantiate another view with the next content you want to show.  Add it to self.view using insertSubview:belowSubview - to put it behind the initial view.  Then when you want to dismiss the first view, animate it's removal as a subview from self.view, which will reveal the second view.